# XSL value-of returns with no value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Trying to copy the element 'ID' and its value from the original XML. Then insert that 'ID' and its value into a new XML under Subheader2.

Currently have been successful in creating the new element under Subheader2 for every subheader for Subheader2. However, 'ID' returns empty and presents only the namespace associated.

Also tried this where the Header/ID was its own template that gets applied. But that only created the 'ID' alone. But, that 'ID' had the correct value.

XML Input

```
<Header xmlns="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo">
  <Date>2019-03-07T14:38:00</Date>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Comment/>
  <Subheader1>
    <Subheader2>
      <Item>A11</Item>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Location>R12</Location>
    </Subheader2>
    <Subheader2>
      <Item>A12</Item>
      <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      <Location>R10</Location>
    </Subheader2>
  </Subheader1>
</Header>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:neo="xmlns="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="neo:Subheader2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="@neo:Header/neo:ID"/>
      </ID>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Output

```
<Header xmlns="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo">
  <Date>2019-03-07T14:38:00</Date>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Comment/>
  <Subheader1>
    <Subheader2>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Item>A11</Item>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Location>R12</Location>
    </Subheader2>
    <Subheader2>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Item>A12</Item>
      <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      <Location>R10</Location>
    </Subheader2>
  </Subheader1>
</Header>
```

Desired XML Output

```
<Subheader1>
  <Subheader2>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Item>A11</Item>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Location>R12</Location>
  </Subheader2>
  <Subheader2>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Item>A12</Item>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    <Location>R10</Location>
  </Subheader2>
</Subheader1>
```

Current XML Output

```
<Header xmlns="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo">
  <Date>2019-03-07T14:38:00</Date>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Comment/>
  <Subheader1>
    <Subheader2>
      <ID xmlns="" xmlns:neo="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo"/>
      <Item>A11</Item>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Location>R12</Location>
    </Subheader2>
    <Subheader2>
      <ID xmlns="" xmlns:neo="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo"/>
      <Item>A12</Item>
      <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      <Location>R10</Location>
    </Subheader2>
  </Subheader1>
</Header>
```

Essentially I'm really after just having the 'ID' element copied into the 'Subheader2'. Really I only want the data in Subheader1/Subheader2 for each Subheader2 but just having the 'ID' added into each 'Subheader2' is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Used xsl:for-each to target only the Subheader2 data.

Discovered that you create variables in XML. Made a variable outside for-each and then used as the value-of within the xsl for-reach of Subheader2.

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="variable" select="neo:Header/neo:ID"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="neo:Header/neo:Subheader1/neo:Subheader2">
      <Subheader2>
        <ID><xsl:value-of select="$variable"/></ID>
        <Item><xsl:value-of select="neo:Item"/></Item>
        <Quantity><xsl:value-of select="neo:Quantity"/></Quantity>
        <Location><xsl:value-of select="neo:Location"/></Location>
      </Subheader2>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This creates the following XML

```
<Subheader2 xmlns:neo="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo">
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Item>A11</Item>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Location>R12</Location>
</Subheader2>
<Subheader2>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Item>A12</Item>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    <Location>R10</Location>
</Subheader2>
```

Comment: That's one solution. The other is to navigate upwards: `<xsl:value-of select="../../neoID"/>`

Comment: Oh? You can navigate upwards? Thank you @MichaelKay. Just learning xslt at the moment and noticed a lot more can be learned outside what is mentioned in w3school.

Thank you. I appreciate that comment.

Comment: w3schools is great at giving a simple explanation of the most commonly used commands. It's a bit like having a crib sheet for your text editor on a single sheet of paper: handy, but only a fraction of what you really need to know to become fully productive.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from what Michael Kay said in comments in another answer, you could also do this....

```
<xsl:value-of select="/neo:Header/neo:ID"/>
```

(So, you were only one character out. `@` represents an attribute, `/` represents the top-level document node).

You also need to add a template to ignore `neo:ID` in its current position

```
<xsl:template match="neo:ID" />
```

But you have one more problem. Doing `<ID>...</ID>` in your template creates an `ID` element in no namespace, which is why you get `xmlns=""` in your output. What you need to do is declare a default namespace in your XSLT so that `ID` elements will be created in that namespace.

```
xmlns="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo"
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:neo="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo" 
                xmlns="urn:stuff:xml:ns:neo" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="neo">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="neo:ID" />

  <xsl:template match="neo:Subheader2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="/neo:Header/neo:ID"/>
      </ID>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that, if you don't want the `neo:Header` element in the output (or the child nodes other than `SubHeader2`, replace the template matching `neo:ID` with this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="neo:Subheader1/neo:Subheader2" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll give this a try when I get home. Appreciate it.